# How to restrict remote access to postgresql docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, security, networking, docker-compose

Using docker-compose I've developed a website which includes a Postgresql database. I deployed it on a server using the same `docker-compose.yml` file, but I found that I can remotely access my postgres server using psql.

I currently have these lines in my docker-compose

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my_website
      POSTGRES_USER: my_website
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
```

Does anybody know how I can only allow access to the postgres db from within the docker network so that it cannot accessed from outside the host OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are binding the port `5432` from within the docker container onto a host port using the `ports` directive. To only have the port accessible within your local docker network, change `ports` to `expose`

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services: 
  db: 
    image: postgres 
    expose: 
      - "5432"
     environment: 
      POSTGRES_DB: my_website
      POSTGRES_USER: my_website
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
```

Comment: I actually found I don't even need to expose that port. It also works without any ports or expose field in the yaml file.

Comment: Great! When the docker image defines an `EXPOSE` section it generally is available within the docker network.